# Angular 2 - Passing Plain Text to Input

Tags: angular, binding

In AngularJS, you could specify `@` (instead of `=`) in a directive in order to bind to plain text. So, with `field: '@'`, you could set the `scope.field` value to the string `"Hello, World"` with the following HTML:

```
<my-tag field="Hello, World" />
```

In Angular 2, I am currently doing the following:

```
<my-tag [field]="'Hello, World'" />
```

Notice the single quotes inside the double quotes. Angular 2 is expecting the contents of the attribute to be an expression.

I was wondering if there is a short-hand to treat the attribute values as plain text? This will help avoid the mistake of forgetting the quotes, which I keep making.

Comment: You can still use the first version. The main difference is that the first will be added to the DOM, while the 2nd will be converted to JS and not be visible in the DOM.

Comment: And if you use `field="Hello, World"`?

Comment: So, drop the brackets (`[]`)? Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that worked. I had no idea based on the documentation that you could do that.

Comment: Well it might be not as clear as day but it's in the docs ;-) You could find it under [Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) in the **[One-time string initialization](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#one-time-string-initialization)** section.

Answer (score 2):

Atleast in the latest version, you can do this in Angular 2 too:

```
<my-tag field="Hello, World" />
```